# Given the following Model, how to determine the User's Role?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

Given the following model:

```
class User < AR::B 
  has_many :permissions 
  has_many :projects, :through => :permissions 
end 
class Project < AR::B 
  has_many :permissions 
  has_many :users, :through => :permissions 
end 
class Role < AR::B 
  has_many :permissions 
end 
class Permission < AR::B 
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :project 
  belongs_to :role 
end
```

In the user.rb model,,, how can I obtain the user's permission for the project?

Something like
self.permissions.role ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an instance method to the User model that took the project as an argument and returned the permission.

```
class User < AR
  def permission_for_project(project)
    permissions.find_by_project_id(project.id)
  end

  def role_for_project(project)
    permission = permissions.find_by_project_id(project.id)

    permission.role unless permission.nil?
  end
end
```

Then use it like:

```
user = User.find(n)
project = Project.find(n)

permission = user.permission_for_project(project)

role = user.role_for_project(project)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's close but it isn't return the role.name from the Roles table. Here is the query from the log: "SELECT "permissions".* FROM "permissions" WHERE ("permissions".user_id = 1) AND ("permissions"."project_id" = 1) LIMIT 1" How can that be updated to return the user's role if any for that project? thxs!

Comment: I updated it to add a method that returned the role for a project. If there's no permission, it will just return nil

Comment: Beerlington has just used `n` to represent the id of the user of project you want to access. You might have `User.find(params[:id])` and `Project.find(params[:project_id])` for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
(the_role = user.permissions.find(:first, project_id => project_id).role) && 
   the_role.name
```

Should look up the (first) permission that the user has for that project and get the role. If there is a role then it will return the name, if not it will return nil.

Comment: Thanks Shadwell your answer was dead on.